# Open Xml Format sdk 2.0 Line Breaks

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk

I have written a function which collects from a two dimensional array. The issue I am having it that I used a string builder to put them both into one string but I would like a break in between

```
public static string[,] ArrSkills = new string[,] 
{
    { "Live The Dream More" }, 
    { "And Even More" } 
};

public static void WriteSkills()
{
    StringBuilder Builder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (string s in ArrSkills)
    {
        Builder.AppendLine(s);
    }
    GetSkills = Builder.ToString(); ;
}
```

The output at the moment is "Live The Dream MoreAnd Even More" when using AppendLine the output has two unknown character symbols where the line break should be. I am writing to a custom XML linked to content controls. I was just wondering how would I be able to spit the array so both parts go on separate lines;

> Live The Dream More
>   And Even More

Answer (score 0):

Just incase any one would like to know I have sorted this issue for getting a break point for my project any way. What I did was use the content control as plain text and then set the properties to "Allow carriage returns". From there I use the code

```
StringBuilder Builder = new StringBuilder();

        string Spacing = Environment.NewLine;

        string newline = "";

        foreach (string s in ArrSkills)
        {
            newline = string.Format("{0}{1}", Spacing, s);

            foreach (var Item in newline)
            {
                Builder.Append(Item);
            }
        }
        GetSkills = Builder.ToString();
```

with allowing Allowing carriage the method for Environment.NewLine allows a line break